# Showing two "infinite " sets have the same cardinality

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Define $X:=\lbrace \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ and $Y:=\lbrace \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}  \rbrace \cup  \mathbb{N}$

So writing this in interval notation I have some function $f$ that maps $(0,1]$ to $(0,1] \cup \mathbb{N}$ I am not sure how to come up with such a function and a inverse to show these 2 have the same cardinality. Is there any way to do these types of problems?

Comment: I do not understand why you are giving two names for sam set....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you mean $Y=X \cup \Bbb N$ and want to prove they have the same cardinality, that $|X|=|Y|$  You have a natural bijection $X \leftrightarrow \Bbb N$, can you define it?  Now you can use the trick you saw that shows a bijection between the even naturals and all the naturals.  Take the $X$ part of $Y$ to the odd naturals and the $\Bbb N$ part of $Y$ to the even naturals, and you have a bijection between $X$ and $Y$.

Note that it is incorrect to view $X$ as the interval $(0,1]$.  You do have $X \subset (0,1]$, but the interval contains (uncountably) many more points than $X$.

Comment: Oh yes I didn't take irrationals into account.

Comment: I'm not seeing it

Comment: I have sketched a bijection $X \leftright arrow \Bbb N$ and another one $Y \leftrightarrow \Bbb N$  If you compose those, you get one between $X$ and $Y$.  Where is the trouble?

Comment: How are you choosing elements in the $X$ part of $Y$ to map to $X$? I see that $\mathbb{N}$ can go to $X$ by defining $1/2n$ and $1/(2n-1)$ but what about elements in $X$?

Comment: Take $1/n\in X \to 2n+1$ and $m \in \Bbb N \to 2m$  That gives a bijection $Y \leftrightarrow \Bbb N$